# Responsive design on a page using Accordions

Tags: 7, views, theming, navigation

I've been wondering how to make the text on this page (http://confluencenter.arizona.edu/events) stop overflowing into the images. I have tried floating the text under the images, but it is reset by some module. I have some experience in CSS but am still very new to Drupal. I did not create this website.

Comment: Tried by adding '!important' to your css attributes?